# Geoserver 2.13.2 cascading WMTS source has wrong source CRS

Tags: geoserver, wmts

I'm trying to cascade this [WMTS Service](https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tiles/service/wmts?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS) in geoserver 2.13.2.

Adding the source causes no additional problems but when creating layers from this source they get imported with the a source CRS of `EPSG:4326`. Looking at the WMTS service this is not a supported CRS.

*When viewing this layer through the Geoserver's WMS the tiles are misaligned and I think this is caused by a faulty reprojection.*

Is there any way to fix this? I've already set the target CRS to a supported one and forced that one to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it is not recognising the provided tilesets and projections, can you [raise a bug](http://geoserver.org/issues/) including the URL of the service being used and I can take a look.

However, as a work round I find that if I set `EPSG:25831` as the declared SRS, it all lines up when I use the tiles in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll file the bug ASAP. I'll check out if it works for me!

Comment: It works fine using `EPSG:25831`. However it still seems to misalign when using `EPSG:28992` which is a requirement for the project I'm working on. Any idea what might cause this? Maybe a faulty CRS definition?

Comment: Not sure, I might get a chance to look over the weekend but I have to prep for a conference so it might not be until September. Consider [commercial support](http://geoserver.org/support/) if it is urgent